# Highcharts: Grouped Columns Chart - Only Plot Non NA Series by Group

Tags: r, highcharts

This is a column type chart made using Highcharts: the series (v1-v7) don't appear in every group (1-4). Is there a Highcharts configuration option that would allow me to get rid of the empty space in each group (plotting only the non NA series by group)?

```
library (rCharts)
`1`<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 100)
`2`<-c(NA,NA,25,NA, 30,50, NA)
`3`<-c(NA,20,NA,25,NA,NA, NA)
`4`<-c(15,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, NA)
data<-as.data.frame(rbind(`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`))

a <- Highcharts$new()
a$chart(type = "column")
a$data(data) 
a$plotOptions(column = list(pointPadding=0))
a$xAxis(style = list(fontSize = "15px"), categories=row.names(data))
a$yAxis(title = list(text = ""), labels = list(format = "{value} %"))
a$legend(enabled = T)
a
```

Comment: Where is image ? its taking to an url seems spam

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi : link updated !

Comment: It would be beneficial if you post a fiddle with your code , simply image can't tell more

Comment: There is no direct setting to do this, no. Post your code or at least your data, or a live fiddle example and we can look at ways to work around.

Comment: @jlbriggs : I just post my code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `category` labeling, I am not sure if there's a good way to do it.

You might look at the Grouped Categories plugin, here:

- http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

Though I am not sure if that can tie in with the rCharts or not.

I might also suggest a different approach to indicating the categories (1-4 in your data), by using just a single series, and specifying a color for each different category, as here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/71/

Or, of course, if you *don't* need to keep that association, you can just send this as one simple series:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/72/